# 'querySelectorAll' on 'document' escaping html attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

This is my html `<a>` element.

```
<a href="javascript:IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$content$PCDZ$MPVG7A7$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl00', &quot;&quot;, false, false, false, '', 0, '', '');">SHARE</a>
```

When I try to query this, I get the following error. It seems like some problem of escaping in the quotes or ` but I have tried all the ways I thought possible.

This is the selector I am trying:

```
$$('a[href="javascript:IDS_LinkButtonClick(\'M$content$PCDZ$MPVG7A7$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl00\', \"\", false, false, false, \'\', 0, \'\', \'\');"]');
```

The error I am getting:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'a[href="javascript:IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$content$PCDZ$MPVG7A7$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl00', "", false, false, false, '', 0, '', '');"]' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: Do it simpler with `$$('a[href*="javascript:IDS_LinkButtonClick(\'M$content$PCDZ$MPVG7A7$ctl00$Accounts"]')`

Comment: Yes I can manage with the incomplete however I want to run this with the complete path

Answer (score 1):

The `\"\"` portion needs to be double-escaped into `\\"\\"` — once for the backslashes and once for the double quotes for the purposes of the attribute selector:

```
$$('a[href="javascript:IDS_LinkButtonClick(\'M$content$PCDZ$MPVG7A7$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl00\', \\"\\", false, false, false, \'\', 0, \'\', \'\');"]');
```